# How to check for any activity on a physical disk?

Tags: bash, filesystem, disk

I have an SD card that's connected via a USB interface.

The output of `fdisk -l` indicates the following:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 3965 MB, 3965190144 bytes
```

I have a script that re-initializes multiple partitions on a disk using `mkfs.ext4` and `mkfs.vfat` commands, all followed by a `sync`. Although the `sync` command finishes with an exit code of 0, the light on the USB SD adapter is still flashing (indicating disk activity).

Currently, in my script I have a count-down timer to just count-down 90 seconds, which I've determined is 'good enough' to ensure that the disk isn't busy before the next operation, but it's really a hack.

**Question:** Is there a generic way to check whether the physical device `/dev/sdb` is being accessed, regardless of operation (i.e. including re-writing partitions, re-reading the partition table using `sfdisk`, or accessing a file on a partition on the disk)?

I've tried `fuser /dev/sdb` and `fuser /dev/sdb*`, but it doesn't achieve this goal - when the light is flashing on the USB SD card adapter, there's not always output from the `fuser` command.

Comment: `dd` is used as part of the script, but not in the area where I experience problems. So this command initializes the disk: `dd if=/dev/zero of=${diskname} count=1 bs=1024`

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If you were using dd there is a command that would tell us if still doing its job</strike>

```
 sudo pkill -USR1 -n -x dd
```

Dont sound like that what you're doing.

I think the reason the activity light is still going after sync is because writing to SD Card tends to be slower...... Or did I totally miss the point

Sorry, couldn't find answer to question about checking if /dev/sdb is in use.

**edit**

Check out iotop

```
 sudo apt-get install iotop
```

Then run it with this command

```
 sudo iotop --only
```

This way it will show you only what in use.

Is this what your looking for?  If not there are some other suggestions [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/198846/ubuntu-tool-for-displaying-disk-activity-in-general-and-by-process)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After reviewing the man page, it appears that this will only work if it's the `dd` command that hasn't finished. I'm looking for something that will indicate any activity (regardless of which process initiated it).

Comment: @CJBS  See my updated answer

Comment: +1 In theory, this should do what I want. I used it in non-interactive mode with the following command-line:  iotop  --batch  --iter=1 -qqq  | grep "dev/sdb"  | grep -v grep
    ... However it seems there's a bug that prevents it from working:  File "/usr/sbin/iotop", line 17, in <module>
... 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 115: ordinal not in range(128)
  ... I think I'll just stay with my countdown timer. Thanks for the help.